# postfix calculator does not work, why? - C

Tags: c, calculator, postfix-notation

i have postfix calculator, but he is not working, can you please help me? 
I want calculate postfix expression `2 sin 2 cos / 5 *`
Output is `5.000000`, but correct output is `0.17...`
Calculations work!
I think the problem is somewhere in adding expressions to the stack.
Thank you for any advice!

```
    const char *arrayPostfix[1000];

        //.
        //.
        //.
        //Filling the field
        //field contents:
        //2 <SIN> 2 <COS> </> 5 <*>

        const char *stack[1000];
        int counter = 0;
        int i;
        int numberofElement = 7; // the number of elements - 2 <SIN> 2 <COS> </> 5 <*>
        char myString[100];
        double help;

        for (i = 0; i < numberofElement; i++) {         


            if (arrayPostfix[i][0] != '<') {
                // IS A NUMBER
                stack[counter] = arrayPostfix[i];
                counter++;

            } else {
                // IT ISNT NUMBER
                //// GET LAST OPERATOR - typedef struct 
                // this works
                operator lastOperator;
                int x = 0;

                for (x = 0; x < sizeof(operatory) / sizeof(operator); x++) {
                    if (strcmp(arrayPostfix[i], operatory[x].nazev) == 0) {
                        lastOperator = operatory[x];
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // Operators are ok..

                double n1, n2;

                if (lastOperator.numberofOperators == 2) {// a+b, a-b, a*b, a/b

                    counter--;
                    n1 = atof(stack[counter]);//string to double


                    counter--;
                    n2 = atof(stack[counter]);//string to double


                    help = lastOperator.funkce_dvaOperator(n2, n1); // this works, calculate
                    sprintf(myString, "%f", help); //double to string

                    stack[counter] = myString;
                    counter++;

                } else { // sin(a), cos(a)....

                    counter--;
                    n1 = atof(stack[counter]); //string to double

                    help = lastOperator.funkce_jedenOperator(n1);   // this works, calculate        

                    sprintf(myString, "%f", help); //double to string

                    stack[counter] = myString;
                    counter++;

                }

            }
                    return atof(stack[0]);
        }
```

steps:

```
1) add number 2
--------------------------------------------
Index [ 0 ] je : 2
--------------------------------------------


2) calculate sin(2)
--------------------------------------------
Index [ 0 ] je : 0.034899
--------------------------------------------


3) add number 2 - but in stac [0] is fail value..why?
--------------------------------------------
Index [ 0 ] je : 0.034899
Index [ 1 ] je : 0.034899
```

Comment: Have you debugged it somehow to reach your conclusion?

Comment: You accidentally a verb in the title

Comment: I used the debugger, I edited the steps in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here is a very big problem:

```
sprintf(myString, "%f", help); //double to string

stack[counter] = myString;
```

Here you set the pointer in `stack[counter]` to point to `myString`. But you forget that `myString` will always be the same pointer, so whenever you change `myString` *all* entries in `stack` that points to `myString` will be changed as it is all the same string.

Comment: @TýnaŠindelářová In C it's not easy. The best bet would probably to have `stack` as an array of arrays (e.g. `char stack[1000][20]`) and use `strcpy` to copy into the strings (or `sprintf` directly into it).

Comment: And what about array only of double value? double stack[1000]..?

Comment: @TýnaŠindelářová Ah yes, that might be even better.

Comment: What about duplicating `myString`, for example by using `strdup()`? Edit: Using `double stack[1000]` is far better.

Comment: @alk Yes, but then you have to remember to `free` the strings all the time as well.